# Pass values from a collection as the first argument of a function

Tags: clojure

Say I have a collection of user-ids i.e. `[001 002 003]`, and then I would have a function that does something and requires the user-id as its first argument.

```
(defn some-function [user-id name e-mail] (do-something user-id name e-mail))
```

What I'd like to do is to use this "some-function" to go through the collection of user-ids so that it would just change the user-id argument but the other arguments would remain the same i.e. so that it would return the following:

=>

```
[(some-function 001 name e-mail) (some-function 002 name e-mail) (some-function 003 name e-mail)]
```

Any help here? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `map`:

```
(map #(some-function % name email) user-ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

If "does something" is side-effecting then you should be using `doseq` rather than `map`:

```
(def user-ids [1 2 3])
(def email "me@my.com")
(def named "me")

(defn some-function [id name email]
  (println (str id ", " name ", " email)))

(doseq [user-id user-ids]
  (some-function user-id named email))
```

"Doing something" normally means affecting the world in some way - from printing to the screen to launching rockets into space.

However if you wanted to return a series of functions that can be executed later then map would be fine:

```
(def fns (map (fn [id]
                (fn []
                  (some-function id named email)))
              user-ids))
```

Here `fns` is the data structure you wrote out in your question.

To actually execute these 'thunks' you still need to `doseq`:

```
(doseq [f fns]
  (f))
```

As a side-note, the kind of function you are talking about, that accepts different arguments at different times, is normally described as a 'higher order function', and it is best to code it that way from the start:

```
(defn some-function-hof [name email]
  (fn [id]
    (println (str id ", " name ", " email))))

(def some-fn! (some-function-hof named email))
```